I'm running a flask app with SSE.. If I open more than a couple of client pages the server seems to hang
I'm running a flask server app, on windows 10, code and template below.  Basically it has a  thread which increments a counter every second, and the backend html gets the updated counter value via SSE. In essence, that works, however, as soon as I open more than 6 copies of the page, page loading never completes.  I'm at a loss as to what is the limiting factor and how I can resolve this.
import os
import time
from pathlib import Path

from flask_debugtoolbar import DebugToolbarExtension

from flask import (
    Flask, Response, stream_with_context, render_template
)

from threading import Thread
from waitress import serve
from gevent import monkey, pool

from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer

monkey.patch_all()

base_dir = Path(__file__).parent.absolute()
app = Flask(__name__,
            template_folder=os.path.join(base_dir, ''))

# the toolbar is only enabled in debug mode:
app.debug = True
# set a 'SECRET_KEY' to enable the Flask session cookies
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '<replace with a secret key>'
app.config['DEBUG_TB_PROFILER_ENABLED'] = True
app.config['DEBUG_TB_PROFILER_DUMP_FILENAME'] = 'profile'
toolbar = DebugToolbarExtension(app)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    # Assuming clients_config is your list of clients and their info
    # Here we modify the parsing to account for the new button structure with hints

    # Pass clients_status to the template if it includes status info
    return render_template('index.html')

counter = 0


def format_sse(time):
    return f"data: {{\"time\": \"{time}\"}}\n\n"


@app.route('/stream_timer')
def stream_timer():
    def timer_stream():
        last_counter = None
        while True:
            # Only send updates if the counter has changed or the game has finished
            if last_counter != counter:
                if counter == 0:
                    time_data = "00:00:00"
                else:
                    hours, remainder = divmod(abs(counter), 3600)
                    minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)
                    time_data = f"{hours:02}:{minutes:02}:{seconds:02}"

                # Prepare the data to send
                formatted_data = format_sse(time=time_data)
                last_counter = counter
            else:
                formatted_data = None

            if formatted_data:
                yield formatted_data
            time.sleep(.1)

    return Response(stream_with_context(timer_stream()), content_type='text/event-stream')


def counterinc():
    global counter
    while True:
        counter += 1
        time.sleep(1)


def run_flask_with_gevent():
    # Define server settings
    # Create a pool of greenlets
    greenlet_pool = pool.Pool(1000)  # Pool of 1000 greenlets

    # Define server settings
    server_settings = {
        'backlog': 256,  # Default is 256
        'spawn': greenlet_pool  # Use the greenlet pool
    }

    # Create the WSGI server with the specified settings
    http_server = WSGIServer(('0.0.0.0', 80), app, **server_settings)
    http_server.serve_forever()


def run_flask_with_waitress():
    serve(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=80, threads=10, connection_limit=1000, backlog=10000)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # start the thread that increments the counter
    Thread(target=counterinc).start()
    # run the flask server
    run_flask_with_gevent()
    # run_flask_with_waitress()

The template (index.html) is as follows :
<html>
<head></head>
<script>
    function listenForTimerUpdates() {
        console.log("listen for timer updates events");
        const evtSource = new EventSource("/stream_timer");
        evtSource.onmessage = function(event) {
            console.log('Timer update:');
            const data = JSON.parse(event.data);

            console.log(data); // Log the received data
            document.getElementById("counter").innerText = event.data; // Update the timer display
        };
    }

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        listenForTimerUpdates();  // Existing function to listen for timer updates
    });
</script>
<body><div id="counter"></div></body>

</html>

I've tried running with plain flask, with waitress, with gevent... Tried increasing nr of threads, nr of workers, nothing changes.  Removing the listenForTimerUpdates() call from javascript, which effectively removes the SSE, resolves the loading issue, so somehow this is directly or indirectly triggered by the SSE setup.
